# How to use url section in index map

Tags: source-maps, transcrypt

I am working on a Python to JavaScript compiler and I try to implement V3 sourcemaps.

The following format works fine:

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "file": "D:/activ_tosh/geatec/transcrypt/transcrypt/demos/pong/__javascript__/pong.mod.js",
    "sources": [
        "D'!activ_tosh!geatec!transcrypt!transcrypt!demos!pong!pong.py"
    ],
    "mappings": "AAAA;AAIA;AAEA;AACA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAEA;AAAA;AAEA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AAEA;AAAA;AAEA;AACA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AAKA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAEA;AACA;AAEA;AACA;AAEA;AACA;AAAA;AAGA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AAEA;AAAA;AAOA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AAMA;AAAA;AACA;AAEA;AACA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AACA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAEA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AACA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAEA;AAEA;AAAA;AAEA;AAGA;AAQA;AACA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AA/CA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AA8CA;AAAA;AAKA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AAMA;AAMA;AAAA;AACA;AAEA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AACA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AAEA;AACA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AAEA;AACA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAvCA;AACA;AAwCA;AAAA;AAKA;AAAA;AAGA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAHA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAKA;AAKA;AAOA;AAAA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AAAA;AAGA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAHA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAKA;AAAA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AAAA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AAvCA;AACA;AAwCA;AAAA;AAEA;AACA;AACA;AAEA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AAEA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AACA;AACA;AAEA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AAEA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AAEA;AACA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AACA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAEA;AAAA;AAAA;AACA;AAAA;AAEA;AAAA;AAAA;AACA;AAAA;AAEA;AAAA;AAAA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AAAA;AACA;AAAA;AAEA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AACA;AAAA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AAEA;AAAA;AACA;AAAA;AAAA;AAEA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA;AAAA"
}
```

but the so called 'index map' format gives an error in Chrome:

```
Failed to parse SourceMap
```

I've looked everywhere for examples, but could find none. Can anyone spot what could be the trouble, my indexmap is:

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "file": "D:/activ_tosh/geatec/transcrypt/transcrypt/demos/pong/__javascript__/pong.js",
    "sections": [
        {
            "offset": {
                "line": 15928,
                "column": 0
            },
            "url": "file:///D:/activ_tosh/geatec/transcrypt/transcrypt/demos/pong/__javascript__/extra/sourcemap/pong.mod.js.map"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried with and without 'file:///' and also relative paths, but this (very uninformative) error remains. I've also tried Firefox devtools, but they give no error info at all.